# Got stuck at Project Euler's question 3 i.e. finding the largest prime factor of a given number. Please see details

Tags: java

So I designed this code (given below) for the question & it seems to be giving all the answers there are but for some reason I'm not able to pass my test cases in the [Hackerrank Question](https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/projecteuler/challenges/euler003/problem) except for the sample one.

My Code :

```
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int t = in.nextInt();
        for(int a0 = 0; a0 < t; a0++){
            BigInteger n = new BigInteger(in.next());
            BigInteger max = BigInteger.valueOf(1);
            for(BigInteger i=BigInteger.valueOf(2);i.multiply(i).compareTo(n)<=0;i=i.add(BigInteger.ONE))
            {
                if(i.isProbablePrime(1) && n.mod(i).compareTo(BigInteger.valueOf(0))==0 && i.compareTo(max)>=0)
                {
                    max = i;
                    n = n.divide(i);
                }
            }
            if(n.isProbablePrime(1))
                max = n;
            else if(n.divide(BigInteger.valueOf(2)).isProbablePrime(1))
                max = n.divide(BigInteger.valueOf(2));
            System.out.println(max);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm getting the same output for each input as this [website](https://jinglescode.github.io/2020/01/06/project-euler-problem-3/) here.

Can anyone please look have a look at my code & point out where am I going wrong. I'm not looking for new code or logic, I just want to know how & why my code or logic is wrong. Can anyone help?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT : NEW CODE** **Found The Solution** Thanks to @Douglas for helping me with hints

```
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int t = in.nextInt();
        for(int a0 = 0; a0 < t; a0++){
            long n = in.nextLong();
            long max = 1;
            while(n%2==0)
                n = n/2;
            if(n==1)
                max = 2;
            for(long i=3;i*i<=n;i+=2)
            {
                while(n%i==0 && i>=max)
                {
                    max = i;
                    n = n/i;
                }
            }
            if(n>2)
                max = n;
            System.out.println(max);
        }
    }
}
```

The code above runs perfectly fine & passes all the testcases.

Comment: @cliff2310 you mean the `if` part? Yes the brackets don't serve a purpose. It's just a habit I guess. Helps me see code a bit clearly. The brackets aren't affecting the output in anyway, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have three problems with this code:

1. An actual bug. You don't handle when a prime divides the number multiple times. I'm fairly sure the four lines before the `println` output are a workaround you put in when you encountered a failure this causes, that fixed the specific failure you found but don't actually address the root cause. I just tested it, your code outputs 3 for the input 252. The correct output for 252 is 7.
2. Part of your code invokes a library method that may be significantly expensive. You should not be using `isProbablePrime`.
3. Your algorithm's logic scales poorly. Hackerrank's test cases probably include something where the correct output is something like 20 digits long. A major point of Project Euler is that it's not enough to write code that will find the correct answer. You need to write code that will find the correct answer **efficiently**. To fix this, you will need new logic for the fundamental design of the program.

Comment: 1. Can you help me out with that. Maybe give a hint as to how should I get around that bug or debug my code? Actually the four lines were not a workaround, they were always a part of condition since I'm only looping till the square root the input hence I need to check if the number itself is a prime value or number's half is a prime number (for example 10's half 5 is a prime or 13 is a prime) hence I used those conditions.
    
2. Actually I don't see any other method to check if a number is prime & since I'm dealing with `BigInteger` because of the input limit I have used it.

Comment: 3. I'm still at beginner stages hence my algorithm skills. But I have checked my hackerrank errors, none of them are for exceeding time limit but for wrong answers hence the reason I'm so adamant on trying my code to work. I know of other logic that can help me solve the challenge but I really want to do it this way. Actually I was up all night trying to redesign the code. Is there anything I can do make this logic error free? Thanks for the input @Douglas

Comment: @meisner97 1. Replace the `if` inside the loop with `while`. With that change, those four lines are pointless because the design of the loop guarantees that `n` will always be either 1 or a prime number by the time the loop finishes. 2. For Project Euler, you should be implementing your own primality checks for any problem that needs them. In this specific case, the primality check is redundant because any non-prime will fail the other parts of the condition too, and those other parts are cheaper to check.

Comment: thanks for the tip.

  `while(BigInteger.valueOf(i).isProbablePrime(1) && n%i==0 && i>=max)
 {
   max = i;  n = n/i;
}`

This is the little change I did & code ran perfectly. Actually I did need the last 4 lines as well since without them it again ran into wrong answers.

  `while(n%i==0 && i>=max)
  {
  max = i;
  n = n/i;
  }`
 
Like you said the primality check is redundant hence removing that works fine too.

Comment: @meisner97 You need *something* where those last 4 lines are, but it can be smaller and simpler. Just check if `n` is 1 or not. If it isn't, then it's prime.

Comment: I did check that but the code is now giving wrong answers again. @douglas

Comment: @meisner97 Edit your new code (that's giving wrong answers) into the question, and I'll see if I can find the problem.

Comment: thanks for all the hints @Douglas. I got a working solution. Do check it out. I have edited the code.

Comment: @meisner97 You can drop the `&& i>=max` part, but the rest looks right.

Comment: Thanks again @Douglas. Can I ask you something related to problem solving in general?

Comment: @meisner97 Go ahead.

Comment: How do you get started on solving problems efficiently, any pointers on that?

Comment: @meisner97 Learn about "big O" performance. Learn how to assess the big O performance of a function. Learn about ways to improve the big O performance of a function. Learn how to identify which parts of a function have the largest impact on its performance, so that you can focus your performance-improvement efforts on those parts. Practice and gain experience to improve your knowledge and skills for all of these things.